# MySQL boolean full text search with subexpressions

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search, information-retrieval

I want to write a boolean full text search query in MySQL. But I want to have results in this order:

`Exact Matches` > `Including all the words` > `Including some of the words`

(`>` means higher.)

With the following query, I get exact matches higher:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>("word1 word2 word3") <(word1 word2 word3)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS score FROM samples WHERE MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>("word1 word2 word3") <(word1 word2 word3)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC
```

With the following query, I get docs that contain all words higher than ones that include some part of the query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>(+word1 +word2 +word3) <(word1 word2 word3)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS score FROM samples WHERE MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>(+word1 +word2 +word3) <(word1 word2 word3)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC
```

But I want to combine these two queries. This is the best I've come to so far but I don't get the results I want.

```
SELECT *, MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>("word1 word2 word3") <(>(+word1 +word2 +word3) <(word1 word2 word3))' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS score FROM samples WHERE MATCH(name,description,address) 
AGAINST('>("word1 word2 word3") <(>(+word1 +word2 +word3) <(word1 word2 word3))' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Is there any way to do this without UNIONs?

Comment: There is no way to do this if there are more than 2 words to match against like `match(..) against('>frist second third')`. You may have to go with `union` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
  SELECT *,
         MATCH (name,description,address) 
           AGAINST ('"word1 word2 word3"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score_exact,
         MATCH (name,description,address) 
           AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score_all,
         MATCH (name,description,address) 
           AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score_some
    FROM samples
   WHERE MATCH (name,description,address) 
           AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score_exact DESC, score_all DESC, score_some DESC
```

Comment: Wow very creative! I think it'll work, I've to test it.

Answer (score 1):

```
( SELECT *,
         1 AS sort_order,       -- top priority to exact match
         1.0 AS extra_ordering
      ... WHERE txt = 'aaaa bbbb cccc' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT *,
         2 AS sort_order,      -- next to all words exist
         MATCH(txt) AGAINST("+aaaa +bbbb +cccc" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      ... WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST("+aaaa +bbbb +cccc" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
( SELECT *,
         3 AS sort_order,      -- finally "any" words
         MATCH(txt) AGAINST("aaaa bbbb cccc" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      ... WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST("aaaa bbbb cccc" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY sort_order ASC, extra_ordering DESC
LIMIT 1;  -- to get the 'best'
```

Comment: My problem with unions is that it returns duplicate records, because the score column is different although the primary key is equal!

Comment: There won't be any duplicates because of the column I added: `sort_order`.  And I added `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: I have to get more results, and the sort order is different for each subquery if a row appears in more than one subquery it will be duplicated.

Comment: Do you want just `txt`, or do you want `*`?  (It makes a big difference in the complexity of how to get more than one result.)

Comment: I want other columns too, I think I could use group by id to get rid of duplicates, is it efficient?

Comment: Then it gets really messy.  You need the _first_ occurrence of each id in that output of the `UNION`, but doing `GROUP BY id` is allowed to pick any row.  So, you need `MAX(...)` to find the best metric when doing the `GROUP BY`.  But then, you have lost the rest of the data.  So you need another `ORDER BY`.  Are you doing this from PHP/Java/etc?  If so, it could pick the first of each pretty easily.  If not, I'll try to concoct the doubly-nested subqueries to do the task.